# Compress VirtualBox Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, compression, lubuntu

I am trying to create a VirtualBox linux virtual machine on which I want to mainly run Wine to install a windows application.

I managed to install Lubuntu 18.04.2, since it is the lightest Ubuntu Distro, but the exported .ova file from VirtualBox is 1.9GB. I am planning to share this VM with other people. So, 1.9GB is a lot to download.

I checked this website ([enter link description here](https://www.osboxes.org/lubuntu/#lubuntu-18-04-vbox)) and there is a Lubuntu 18.04.2 VM which has a size of 899MB. How did they do that?

Comment: Um... Why not install Windows in the VM? Is it due to a size restriction that you have?

Comment: I want to share this VM with other users. Windows needs a license key.

Comment: See also [How to compact VirtualBox's VDI file size?](https://superuser.com/questions/529149/how-to-compact-virtualboxs-vdi-file-size)

Comment: @Sjoerd I used the method in your link but I am still not able to reach to the size of file from the website I mentioned in my main post. One thing I noticed is that their file is .vdi but my file is .ova

Comment: Maybe the size of Swap file is effecting the size of the .ova file? Could anyone approve or disapprove this?